# On key board handler in linux using c programing

Tags: c, linux

I am trying a program in c that controls keyboard handler to blink <kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd> & <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> LED's as a reaction of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> push... please help me..

Comment: I don't know why I find this thread funny, but it is.

Comment: Isn't ctrl+alt+del handled in the kernel?

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, as you specified using C.

Comment: The program source code is available here: http://www.kernel.org

Comment: This thread sounds a lot like homework. By the way, where's the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda agree with KP.  This is funny...

But if yer serious...

**First:**

There's a ***setleds*** program that might help you get started.  It's been around for ages...  Try ***man setleds***.

Also, ***xset*** can be used (under X-windows) to change leds...  (You may have to see which leds are enabled for changing in the X-config file.)

**Second:**

Detecting *ctrl+alt+del* is more of an issue as it's flagged specially by *init*.  Look in */etc/inittab* or */etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf* or someplace like that, and you'll see lines like:

```
# Trap CTRL-ALT-DELETE
ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t3 -h now
```

Or:

```
# control-alt-delete - emergency keypress handling
#
# This task is run whenever the Control-Alt-Delete key combination is
# pressed.  Usually used to shut down the machine.

start on control-alt-delete

exec /sbin/shutdown -r now "Control-Alt-Delete pressed"
```

So you'd have to disable that...  Or simply have it run your keyboard-blink program rather than /sbin/shutdown.

Also, watch out for  *"Control-Alt-Backspace"* -- Many X11 config setups enable this combination to shutdown the X server.  (Option *"DontZap"*.)

**Third:**

Now you need to find a way to pickup the *control-alt-delete* keypress.  It's not impossible, but it may not be as simple as *getc()*.  (The again, I could be wrong...)

Of course, if you don't want your program to have the keyboard focus.  If you want this to happen while other programs are running in the foreground with keyboard focus...  Well then yer looking at tweaking the kernel or some kernel driver.  (Or having *inittab* run yer program instead of  */sbin/shutdown*.)

**Any way you slice it, this is not a good *Hello World* type exercise.**

Answer (score 1):

Option:

- Find the right place to trap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and register a handler.
- Use the `KDGETLED/KDSETLED` ioctl on `/dev/console` to changes the keyboard LEDs.

Good Luck!